# Alert delay - iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, delay

i'm creating a game, whenever the user answers correctly or the time is done an alert will be presented. im using SweetAlert class from GitHub.
a sound will be played just before the alert get presented.
im facing an annoying problem. i keep getting a delay when the alert shows the first time. all other times are fine.

i thought that the problem is with the sound, i used prepareToPlay and i tried to run the sound on background queue but still the same.

here is my code.

this code is for when the game is over

```
func updateTime() {
    let shouldTimerStop = timeManager.updateTime()
    if timeManager.time <= 30 {
        timerLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        SoundManager.backgroundMusicSharedInstance!.volume = 0.05
        //if !clockSoundIsPlaying {
        SoundManager.playClockSound()
            //clockSoundIsPlaying = true
        //}
    }
    timerLabel.text = timeManager.displayedTime(timeManager.time)
    if shouldTimerStop {
        SoundManager.clockSoundSharedInstance!.stop()
        //SoundManager.backgroundMusicSharedInstance?.volume = 0.05
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = NSTimer()
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
            SoundManager.playGameOverSound()
        })
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        SweetAlert().showAlert("Game Over!", subTitle: "Better luck next time!", style: AlertStyle.Error, buttonTitle:"Restart", buttonColor:UIColor(red: 56.0/255.0, green: 163.0/255.0, blue: 221.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0) , otherButtonTitle:  "Main Menu", otherButtonColor: UIColor(red: 56.0/255.0, green: 163.0/255.0, blue: 221.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)) { (isOtherButton) -> Void in
            if isOtherButton == true {
                self.score = 0
                self.scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(self.score)"
                self.timeManager.resetTimer()
                self.resetUI()
            }
            else {
                // go to main menu
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backToMainMenu", sender: self)
            }
            SoundManager.backgroundMusicSharedInstance!.volume = 0.2
        }

    }
}
```

and here is the code for when the answer is correct

```
func correctAnswer() {
        SoundManager.backgroundMusicSharedInstance!.volume = 0.05
        if self.timeManager.time <= 30{
            SoundManager.stopClockSound()
        }
        let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
            SoundManager.playCorrectSound()
        })
        self.timer.invalidate()
        SweetAlert().showAlert("Good job!", subTitle: "You passed the level!", style: AlertStyle.Success, buttonTitle:"Continue", buttonColor:UIColor.init(red: 56/255, green: 163/255, blue: 221/255, alpha: 1)) { (isOtherButton) -> Void in
            if isOtherButton == true {
                self.continueWithTheGame()

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: The problem was because of SweetAlert class, i fixed by initializing the class at the beginning of my code.

Answer (score 2):

Were you testing on a simulator or a real device? It could just be your device. If you are using a simulator, it could be lag. That happened with my app, but it just stopped happening. There doesn't seem to be anything in your code that could be causing this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This question seems to have a similar issue...

[Very strange issue in Swift code. Delay to make operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547831/very-strange-issue-in-swift-code-delay-to-make-operations)